# How to switch between front camera and rear camera in javascript?

Tags: javascript, getusermedia

```js
let constraints;
function handleVideo(){
const constraints = {
  video: {
    facingMode: {
      exact: 'user'
    }
  }
};

var video;
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).
then((stream) => {
  video = document.createElement("video")
  video.srcObject = stream
  video.play()
  video.onloadeddata = () => {
    ctx.height = video.videoHeight
  }
})
}
```

I know by changing `exact` to `environment` can switch between front and back camera. But I don't know how to do this onclick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this :

```js
function handleVideo(cameraFacing) {
  const constraints = {
    video: {
      facingMode: {
        exact: cameraFacing
      }
    }
  }
  return constraints
};

function turnVideo(constraints) {
  let video;
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then((stream) => {
      video = document.createElement("video")
      video.srcObject = stream
      video.play()
      video.onloadeddata = () => {
        ctx.height = video.videoHeight
      }
    })

}

document.querySelector(".frontCamera").addEventListener("click", () => {
  turnVideo(handleVideo("user"));
})
document.querySelector(".backCamera").addEventListener("click", () => {
  turnVideo(handleVideo("environment"));
})
```

```html
<div class="frontCamera">front</div>
<div class="backCamera">back</div>
```

Comment: Can you please tell me where are these mistakes ?

Comment: So, that I can edit the answer and make it useful for others.

Comment: It doesn't work, gives Dom exception error ```code: 0
message: "Could not start video source"
name: "NotReadableError" ```

Comment: Logic would be something like this.

Comment: The correct spelling is - "environment". Please fix.